# Ajax Requst Fails - Java / Json

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I'm pretty new to AJAX and I feel like I have a syntax error but I have not been able to spot it and don't want to waste another hour and half looking for it.

I'm using Spring security to login to the application, which works fine. Upon successfully logging in I re-route them to 'index.jsp.' index.jsp has a $(document).ready function with an ajax routine that calls the controller and requests the data. I know the controller portion works, it's the javascript that appears to be failing.

Also, the error block within the ajax routine does not fire.

Without further ado..

**Javascript**

```
 var authorTableBody = document.getElementById('authorTableData');
 var $body = $('body');
 $(document).ready(function () {

 if ($body.attr('class') === "splash") {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "AuthorController?action=listAjax",
        success: function (authors) {
            getAllAuthors(authors);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Could not get authors for this user due to: " + errorThrown.toString());
        }
    });

}
});

function getAllAuthors(authors) {
var index = 0;
var tableParts;
$.each(authors, function () {
    index++;
    tableParts = ["<tr id='row" + index.toString() + "'" + "class='authorTableDataRow' >",
        "<td>", authors.authorId, "</td>",
        "<td>", authors.firstName, "</td>",
        "<td>", authors.lastName, "</td>",
        //"<td>",authors.size,"</td>",
        "</tr>"];
});
authorTableBody.append(tableParts.join());
}
```

**Controller**

```
  if (action != null) {
        try {

            String authorID = request.getParameter("authorID");
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            Author author = new Author(0);
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            switch (action) {

                case "loadTable":

                    List<Author> authors = authorService.getAllAuthors();
                    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

                    authors.forEach((authorObj) ->{
                        jsonArrayBuilder.add(
                             Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                .add("authorId", authorObj.getAuthorID())
                                .add("firstName", authorObj.getAuthorFirstName())
                                .add("lastName", authorObj.getAuthorLastName())
                                //.add("size", authorObj.getBookCollection().size())
                        );
                    });

                JsonArray authorsJson = jsonArrayBuilder.build();
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                pw.write(authorsJson.toString());
                pw.flush();
                return;
```

**HTML** (index.jsp)

```
     <div id="authorTableDataContainer">
        <form id="authorDeleteForm" action="AuthorController?action=delete" method="POST">
            <table id="authorTable" style="text-align: center;">

                <thead>
                <th> Author ID </th>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Last Name </th>
                <th> Delete </th>
                <th View</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="authorTableData">

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </form>

    </div>
```

**webconfig.xml**

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">

 <!-- Begin Spring-specific configuration -->
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
<!-- END Spring configuration -->

   <!-- begin additional Spring Security config -->
 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
<!-- end Spring security config -->

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BookController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.wctc.asp.bookwebapp.controller.BookController</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>


 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BookController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BookController</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: `authorTableBody.append(tableParts.join());` Have defined `authorTableBody` yet, could not find it in the code. Most likely its error out at that line. Could you open up the JavaScript console and check it?

Comment: it's there, it just didn't make the cut when i copied and pasted everything over. Unfortunately it does not make it that far. It dies on the **success** block;

Comment: Can I confirm if your relative URL `AuthorController?...` is fine. This is relative to the current path. i.e. if your current page is mypage.jsp this path will be `mypage.jsp/AuthorController?....`. Then can you put a `console.log(JSON.stringify(authors));` after `success:function(authors){` to see if you are getting response there?

Comment: @amitthk I like your style! Ill add the XML and appContext to make it a little clearer.

Comment: So after logging in, you are redirected to the index.jsp which is indicated by the <welcome-file> tags in the xml. From there the index.jsp has a $(document).ready function calling the js i provided. The controller is getting called and the code inside works.

Comment: alright, so that definately help. I can handle it from here. Thanks @amitthk

Comment: Great to hear it helped. So probably either your relative URL seems to be issue here. Otherwise if you're already getting a response, check it by `console.log(JSON.stringify(` it. Then probably we can think about debugging the table processing further. Do give me a vote up if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: If the ajax is fired then either success or error will be executed . But as you mentioned, you are not seeing either of them. So just check if  ajax is firing or not.So put a console.log or alert to verify this if ($body.attr('class') === "splash") is executing or not.Also check from developers tool if ajax url is getting hitted or not.